# Extra vertical line appeared at the end of a line

Tags: latex

I am using latex with `\documentclass[A4paper, 12pt]{book}` to write my PhD thesis, and I have some long chapter titles. However, an extra vertical line appeared as is shown in the figure below.

[image]

I checked for the whole thesis and found that this verticle line symbol always appears when a line is too long. How could I remove this symbol?

Such things wouldn't appear if I use `article` class instead of `book`.

Comment: Please consider providing an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are more likely to get help if you provide it.

Comment: This could be a marker that shows overly long lines in draft mode.

Answer (score 1):

The line indicates overfull boxes in `draft` mode. It would be better to fix the overfull line warning, but if you just want to remove the line, remove the `draft` option:

```
\documentclass[
% draft
]{book}
```